# I am trying to subtract 3 hours from a method that I have created but I am getting an error

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, time, dst

I have successfully created a DST method called dst_datechange that takes a date, is parsed out using Time.parse. It looks like this:

```
require 'time'
def dst_datechange(date)
  date = Time.parse(date.to_s) # if date.class.eql?(String)
  case
  when (date > Time.parse('March 11, 2018 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('November 4, 2018 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse('November 4, 2018 2:00am')
    puts "the date rounded to november 4, 2018"
  when (date > Time.parse('November 4 2018, 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('March 10, 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse('March 10, 2019 2:00am')
    puts "the date rounded to march 10 2019"
  when (date > Time.parse('March 10, 2019 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('November 3, 2019 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse('November 3, 2019 2:00am')
  when (date > Time.parse('November 3, 2019 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('March 8, 2020 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse('March 8, 2020 2:00am')
  when (date > Time.parse('March 8, 2020 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('November 1, 2020 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse ('November 1, 2020 2:00am')
  else
    raise "The date #{date} does not match any dst date parameter"
  end
  date
  puts "the new DST date is #{date}"
end
```

and my "puts" displays this...

```
the date rounded to: november 4, 2018 
 the new DST date is now: 2018-11-04 02:00:00 -0600
```

Now that I am receiving the correct date, I have a step that takes that `dst_datechange` and performs a subtraction, however, I am getting an error that says:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Integer into Array
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I know its most likely a formatting issue where I am trying to subtract a date time object with just a time object. here is my step below where the stacktrace is pointing the failure at:

```
  date = (dst_datechange(Time.now) - (60*60*3))
  puts "the date is now adjusted 3 hours back from 2:00am:  #{date} "
end
```

I am unsure how to format that (60*60*3) to subtract 3 hours from that new November `2018-11-04 02:00:00 -0600` date and basically roll it back to `2018-11-03 23:00:00 -0600`

Comment: If you have an error that includes a method you created, it might make sense to include that method. We can't debug your code without even seeing it.

Comment: alright, just added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method def dst_datechange(date) doesn't return the date you want it to, but instead puts your string.

When you call that in your second part, dst_datechange(Time.now), that doesn't return the date, but the return value for the last puts.

Try calling 'date' again after your final puts in your dst_datechange method:

```
when (date > Time.parse('March 8, 2020 2:00am')) && (date < Time.parse('November 1, 2020 2:00am'))
date = Time.parse ('November 1, 2020 2:00am')
  else
    raise "The date #{date} does not match any dst date parameter"
  end
  puts "the new DST date is #{date}"
  date
end
```

Comment: so, delete the 'date' return value at the end of my case and rather put it inside of one of the cases?

Comment: @AA. No, return the date *after* the `puts`. Ruby has implicit returns: whatever is last in the method is what is returned.

Comment: irregardless of me doing that, i just ran it and I am still getting the same error...

Comment: I dont exactly need the puts anyways knowing that the method is working correctly which was half of the battle. I just need the calculation to work

Comment: Then make sure the last command before your final 'end' is 'date' in your dst_datechange method

Comment: MOTHER OF GOD ITS WORKING

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want to subtract hours.  Try:

```
(Time.now - 3.hours).to_datetime
```

Or, if using ActiveSupport you can specify that you want three hours ago:

```
3.hours.ago
```

Comment: Pure Ruby doesn't have a method `Integer.hours`. You need to replace `3.hours` with `3*60*60`.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2007, in most jurisdictions in the United States and Canada, Daylight Saving Time ("DST") has begun at 2:00am on the second Sunday of March, and ended at 2:00am on the first Sunday in November. In Mexico, DST begins at 2:00am on the first Sunday in April and ends at 2:00am on the last Sunday in October. The experience varies in other parts of the world.<sup>1</sup>

Given a `Time` object (possibly computed from a string representation of a time) your code returns a second `Time` object equal to the time at which the next time change occurs, from DST to STD or vice-versa (i.e., in those parts of the United States and Canada that have adopted DST). There is no need to hard-wire those dates. The calculation can be done as follows.

```
require 'time'

def dst_datechange(time)
  year = time.year
  if time.dst?
    start_std(year)
  else
    year += 1 if time >= Time.new(year, 11)
    start_dst(year)
  end
end

def start_std(year)
  date = Date.new(year, 11)
  date += (7-date.wday) % 7
  Time.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, 2)
end

def start_dst(year)
  date = Date.new(year, 3, 8)
  date += (7-date.wday) % 7
  Time.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, 2)
end

['June 17, 2018 1:00pm', 'November 4, 2018 12:59am', 'November 4, 2018 1:00am',      
 'March 10, 2019 1:59am', 'March 10, 2019 2:00am'].
  each do |s|
    t = DateTime.strptime(s, '%B %e, %Y %l:%M%P').to_time
    t = Time.new(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec)
    puts "#{s}: #{ dst_datechange(t) }"
  end
  June     17, 2018  1:00pm: 2018-11-04 02:00:00 -0800
  November  4, 2018 12:59am: 2018-11-04 02:00:00 -0800
  November  4, 2018  1:00am: 2019-03-10 03:00:00 -0700
  March    10, 2019  1:59am: 2019-03-10 03:00:00 -0700
  March    10, 2019  2:00am: 2019-11-03 02:00:00 -0800
```

Notice that the first, second and last examples return a time whose hour is `2`. This is in fact one hour after the time changed. The other two examples return an hour of `3`, which is an instant after the time changed. Note:

```
Time.new(2019, 3, 10, 2)
  #=> 2019-03-10 03:00:00 -0700
Time.parse('March 10, 2019 2:00am')
  #=> 2019-03-10 03:00:00 -0700
```

In future, DST date ranges could change (as they did in 2007) or DST could be [eliminated altogether](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-45366390). In production code, therefore, it would be prudent to address these possibilities. Assuming the method [Time#dst?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Time.html#method-i-dst-3F) would continue to exist, `Time.new(year,6).dst?` should tell us if we still have DST, and if so, one could search day-by-day to see when the time changes occur.

<sup>1. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)</sup>